# php - Masking a Phone Number regardless of length

Tags: php

I've tried the following functions

`str_repeat("*", strlen($value['number'])-2) . substr($value['number'], -2)`

and `str_pad(substr($value['number'], -2), strlen($value['number']), '*', STR_PAD_LEFT)`

However they both yield the same result: `******43`

---

What I am tying to achieve is this: `70****43`, but dynamically regardless of number length.

Any suggestions how it can be done?

Comment: Where is the part where you keep the first parts of the number? Obviously, both attempts don't include them. Additionally, this would be a perfect candidate to exercise TDD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See below:

```
$num = '70564843';

echo substr( $num, 0, 2 ) // Get the first two digits
     .str_repeat( '*', ( strlen( $num ) - 4 ) ) // Apply enough asterisks to cover the middle numbers
     .substr( $num, -2 ); // Get the last two digits
```

Output:

```
70****43
```

Comment: Not what I'm looking for. It's not dynamic...I need to manually specify the number of asterisks.

Comment: @Borsn what does "manually specify" mean? Why didn't you include such a requirement in your initial question?

Comment: @Borsn instead of `strlen( $num )` you can put whatever variable/number you want

Comment: @Borsn I really don't understand. It would be very helpful if you provided multiple examples of expected output.

Comment: This `str_repeat( '*', ( strlen( $num ) - 4 ) )` does not make it dynamic. The `4` works for some numbers but not for longer numbers.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Sorry about that...does work as intended. Just figured out what the . `4` was for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of dynamic:

```
$phoneNumber = 123456789; //your phone number
$showFirstDigits = 2; //how many digits to show in the beggining of the phone number
$showLastDigits = 2; // how many digits to show in the end of the phone number
echo(
    substr_replace($phoneNumber,str_repeat('*',strlen($phoneNumber) - $showFirstDigits - $showLastDigits),
                   $showFirstDigits,
                   strlen($phoneNumber) - $showFirstDigits - $showLastDigits));
```